# Revenge of the Sith - What they are taking revenge for?

Tags: star-wars, revenge-of-the-sith, title-explanation

*Star Wars Episode III* was titled as *Revenge of the Sith*. This title confuses me. We see Sidious and Vader getting rid of all Jedi which may be a part of revenge. **However, what they are taking revenge for?**